# Creating an excel database

Tags: database, excel

I am building an excel database, the size of the database will be approximately 1000000 rows of data per year.

I have ran into a problem. Data will be entered to the same database by approximately 12 different people, which causes a problem that the database file will be Read-only most of the day. What options do i have to allow all those people to enter data simultaneously?

Also all those people will be entering numbers based on different categories, which would require a different user interface for data input for each one of them.

Comment: Perhaps a different spreadsheet for each user's interface. Each of those would, when submitted by the user, open the main DB workbook and insert their record(s) that they created, save it, and close it. There might still be overlaps as multiple users submit at the exact same time, but it solves both problems. Better yet though... put the DB in a DB like SQL server or Access if you can't get a SQL server environment up and running. 1000000 rows in excel is pushing it to the brink.

Comment: Agree, 1000000 rows is a lot for Excel. Especially when you start processing that data.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2013 will allow multiple users to edit the same file simultaneously if (1) you have the business/enterprise version and (2) the file is kept on the OneDrive cloud (which is included in the business version).

All the users will be able to see the other users' edits in real time.  Each user's cursor shows up as a different color.

Alternatively, consider using QUICKBASE.COM.  It is an easy-to-use cloud-based database designed for multiple simultaneous users.  If you can figure out how to use Excel, you'll be able to figure out how to use QUICKBASE.  It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If company security policy excludes a cloud solution, 1 million records is unwieldy for either Excel or Access. Check the system limits for both and you will see what you are up against.

If you are still forced to use Excel, each user can be set up with their own data entry template with VBA to copy their additions to a master Excel file. This would overcome the read only issue. If you are looking at updating records once added, you are opening a new can of worms from a coding perspective.